# JNA - callback method with typedef struct** argument

Tags: java, callback, jna

I am using C dll with this code:

1)

```
AIC_BRIDGE_API AIC_ERROR_CODE aic2_set_cb_function (
    void (*cb2_start_dsts) (AIC2_DSTS_START_STOP),
    void (*cb2_stop_dsts) (AIC2_DSTS_START_STOP),
    void (*cb2_dsts_rcvd_ex) (unsigned int, unsigned long *, char *, AIC2_DSTS_STO),
    void (*cb2_log) (const char *, int, const char *, int)
);
```

2)

```
aic2_set_cb_function (NULL, NULL, cb2_dsts_rcvd_ex, NULL);
```

The dll runs in many apps with C/C++ and .Net code.
My code in Java is this:

1)

```
public interface ReadCallbackInt extends Callback {
    void invoke(int iNumDv, Pointer pMicDv, String pcARName, AIC2_DSTS_STO.ByValue sto);
}
```

2)

```
public void aic2_set_cb_function(StartDSCallbackInt fn1, 
                           StopDSCallbackInt fn2, 
                           ReadCallbackInt fnReadCB,
                           LogCallbackInt fn4);
```

3)

```
TestLib.ReadCallbackInt fnReadCB = new TestLib.ReadCallbackInt() {
    long[] IntArray;

    @Override
    public void invoke(int iNumDv, Pointer pMicDv, String pcARName, AIC2_DSTS_STO.ByValue sto) {
        if (sto.bTsNamePres > 0) {
            System.out.println("iNumDv: " + iNumDv);
            System.out.println("pMicDv: " + pMicDv);
            System.out.println("pcARName: " + pcARName);
            System.out.println("sto: " + sto.TsName);
            if (pMicDv!=null) {
                IntArray = new long[iNumDv]; 
                IntArray = pMicDv.getLongArray(0, iNumDv);
                if (IntArray != null) {
                    System.out.println("IntArray: " + IntArray +" First El. " + IntArray[0]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...............
...............

4)

```
TestLib.INSTANCE.aic2_set_cb_function(null, null, fnReadCB, null);
```

The issue is that in IntArray I get all elements as zero. Can you help me?

5) Original C code:

```
void cb2_dsts_rcvd_ex (unsigned int iNumDv, unsigned long *piMicDv, char *pcARName, AIC2_DSTS_STO sto)

{
    unsigned int i;
    AIC2_DV *pdv;

    printf ("\nRemote %s: ", pcARName);
    if (sto.bTsNamePres)
        printf ("Report (%s/%s) received\n", sto.TsName.pcDomainName, sto.TsName.pcName);
    else
        printf ("Report (unknown) received\n");
    for (i = 0; i < iNumDv; i++)
        if (piMicDv[i] != AIC_ID_DV_INVALID)
        {
            pdv = aic2_get_dv_info (piMicDv[i]);
            log_data_values_aic2 (pdv, stdout);
            if (pdv) aic2_free_dv_info(pdv);
        }
}
```

Comment: Try converting your Java string to a C string for the `pcARName` parameter using the pattern in the top answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158582/converting-string-to-pointer-for-jna/10210584

Comment: @Daniel Widdis, thanks for the advice, but I am getting pcARName correct. The issue is in the second argument pMicDv. It is a C array of pointers and it is defined as parameter "unsigned long *". I have tried in Java Pointer, Memory, LongByInteger, etc. but without success. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: There's some conflicting terminology here. You're calling it an `IntArray` but defining it as `long[]` and now stating it's an array of Pointers (which would be `void *` in C)?  A native `long` should be mapped to a `NativeLong` in JNA.  I never see where the length of the array `iNumDv` is set (you pass `NULL` in snippet #2 which would be a pointer to 0 so perhaps you're telling the native function to return a 0-length array). Actually you're passing null to the outer function for all the args... that doesn't seem right...

Comment: @Daniel Widdis, yes that is true with conflicting terminology. I am not native speaker, sorry. For that reason I will post my old C code here which runs in many apps:

Comment: void cb2_dsts_rcvd_ex (unsigned int iNumDv, unsigned long *piMicDv, char *pcARName, AIC2_DSTS_STO sto)
{
 unsigned int i;
 AIC2_DV *pdv;

 printf ("\nRemote %s: ", pcARName);
 if (sto.bTsNamePres)
  printf ("Report (%s/%s) received\n", sto.TsName.pcDomainName, sto.TsName.pcName);
 else
  printf ("Report (unknown) received\n");
 for (i = 0; i < iNumDv; i++)
  if (piMicDv[i] != AIC_ID_DV_INVALID)
  {
   pdv = aic2_get_dv_info (piMicDv[i]);
   log_data_values_aic2 (pdv, stdout);
   if (pdv) aic2_free_dv_info(pdv);
  }
}

Comment: And this code I want to translate now in Java.

Comment: Comments don't format code well. Please edit your question to include the working C code.

Comment: already done as 5)

Comment: @Daniel Widdis, is it possible this C code to port to Java at all?

Comment: I'm still not following how you pass the arguments to the callback function in either your code or the original C.  For example the first argument of your `invoke()` method is `iNumDv`.  Nowhere do I see that integer given any value.

Comment: Please check the C code loop in 5)  <<  for (i = 0; i < iNumDv; i++)  >>. I have comment out similar loop in java because the first element in IntArray was 0. And the rest elements were also 0. And this is my java issue, not iNumDv.

Comment: I see it in (5) but that's still taken from the argument list.  Look at (2): `aic2_set_cb_function (NULL, NULL, cb2_dsts_rcvd_ex, NULL);` you are setting the callback function by name, without any other arguments.  Where (in C) do you set the value of the parameters `unsigned int iNumDv, unsigned long *piMicDv, char *pcARName, AIC2_DSTS_STO sto`?  Where do you set the equivalent in Java?  Is that provided by the API you're using?  What is the complete output of the debug `System.out.println()` statements in your snippet (3)?

Comment: I am setting in C the value of the parameters unsigned int iNumDv, unsigned long *piMicDv, char *pcARName, AIC2_DSTS_STO sto in the library (DLL or SO). And I am using the same C DLL in Java and that is provided by its API. The complete output of the debug System.out:
<<<
iNumDv: 11
pMicDv: native@0x31ba54
pcARName: SiteA
sto: TestJava$TestLib$AIC2_OBJ_REF$ByValue(allocated@0x35a5ec (132 bytes) (shared from auto-allocated@0x35a5e8 (152 bytes))) {
  char iScope@0x0=?
  byte pcDomainName[65]@0x2=[B@f7f36a
  byte pcName[65]@0x43=[B@1faab1
}
IntArray: [J@171fc7e First El. 0
>>>

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with what you've provided but without seeing the original API documentation I don't know if it's telling you any other steps you have to take.  One thing you didn't do is map the error code of `aic2_set_cb_function` to a return value in Java so you can test whether the call actually succeeded. It's possible that it is failing and giving you useful debug information in the error.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have mapped the error code of aic2_set_cb_function to a return value in Java. The return value was 0 -> no errors. Other advice?